# How to change only one value of a key, in a map, using Typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary

How can I change only one value of a key in a map ?
I have the following code:

```
const userMap_secretkey = new Map<number, [string | undefined, string | undefined, number, boolean] >();
```

Lets say I have an entry like this: (12345, [isok, isnotok, 2, false)
Hoe can I change only the last value from false to true ?

Thank you

I am now using the code bellow but Im more then sure that there is another way to do this.

```
userId = ctx.from.id;
  userMap_secretkey.set(userId, [userMap_secretkey.get(userId)?.[0], userMap_secretkey.get(userId)?.[1], userMap_secretkey.get(userId)![2], true])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since arrays are objects, and maps will give you the reference to that object, you can simply get the entry and then change the element at index 3 like this:

```js
const userId = ctx.from.id;

if (userMap_secretkey.has(userId)) {
    userMap_secretkey.get(userId)![3] = true;
} else {
    // does not exist in map
}
```